# object Object is not a PostCSS plugin | PostCSS Autoprefixer

Tags: gruntjs, postcss, autoprefixer

I am trying to use Grunt PostCSS Autoprefixer but it keeps saying that it is not a PostCSS plugin:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "test",
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.6",
    "grunt": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^4.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^5.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-postcss-import": "0.0.1",
    "grunt-prettify": "^0.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
postcss: {
  options: {
    map: {
      inline: false,
      annotation: 'dist/css/maps/'
    },
    processors: [
      // require('pixrem')(),
      require('autoprefixer')(),
      //require('cssnano')()
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    src: 'dist/css/bundle.css'
  }
},
```

I made sure to first remove the `grunt-autoprefixer` and install `autoprefixer` which should be a postcss plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was just a version compatibility issue. I simply changed:

```
"autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
```

with:

```
"autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
```